# Parsing mass selection id from the product grid

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, massaction, product-grid

I made a new item in the action list from the product grid. This is my file, ui_component/product_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="create_barcode">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">create_barcode</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create Barcode(s)</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="myurl/product/massCreateBarcode"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

In my controller(massCreateBarcode):

```
class MassCreateBarcode extends Action
{

    private $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Product Barcode(s)'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

in my layout, i have this:

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Barcode\View" name="my_name" template="Namespace_Module::barcode/view.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

and in my block (Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Barcode\View) i have this method:

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $products = [];
    $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected');

    if (!isset($productIds)) {
        return [];
    }
    foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
        $products[] = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    }
    return $products;
}
```

the method: `getProducts` is called in the template(phtml file). My problem is that if I do a filtering on the grid after the name, select a couple of products and do the mass action, the result of this code from my method is null:

```
$productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected');
```

If I reset the product grid and do the same thing. I get the products ids. So something is wrong when I filter my grid and do the mass action. Does anyone know what should I check ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: why you want to perform this code from block?

Comment: @RohanHapani I have a custom template file, which needs to be rendered and where I need the selected product ids.